# phonegap facebook connect integration issue

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am trying to integrate my phonegap application with facebook through facebook connect plugin. I followed the instructions [here](http://marguspala.com/add-facebook-login-to-phonegap-android-app-easiest-way/) since git wasn't working for me but I think I would end up with the exact same setup either way.

When I run the following code after doing FB.init() using my app ID, I get an alert saying "Cordova Facebook Connect Plugin failed on auth.status"

```
console.log('Debug 1');
var params = {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  };
console.log(params);
FB.ui(params, function(obj) { console.log(obj);});
```

While logcat output shows this:

```
09-03 21:29:00.230: D/CordovaLog(21824): Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found
09-03 21:29:00.230: D/CordovaLog(21824): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js: Line 938 : Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found
09-03 21:29:00.230: I/Web Console(21824): Error: Status=2 Message=Class not found at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:938
```

I don't know if this is an issue with facebook authentication of my app or some code issue. I have generated an Android Hash Key using the keytool and submitted it to facebook developer page. When I export my android project as android application in eclipse using the same keystore, it doesn't show me the alias I used with keytool (same keystore). So I created a new alias with the same alias name and password and then install the apk on my phone. What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Well there were many problems. First of all, and most confusing was that the following line is not to be placed in plugins.xml but in config.xml instead.

```
<plugin name="com.phonegap.facebook.Connect" value="com.phonegap.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
```

After that, I had not entered the correct hash key at facebook developer page. Since you don't want to export an apk through a keystore every time you need to test your app, you should just run the debugging apk generated by eclipse (Run as > Android application) and attempt FB.login(). Facebook will give you an error that your key is 'xxxxxx' and it does not match the keys listed at your app page. Note 'xxxxxxx' down and enter it on the facebook app page.

Others were my own mistakes of not including the scripts in the correct order. I had not followed the example carefully. Be sure you get the example/Simple/index.html working first before you code for your own application. Hope it helps...